# How to Apply Like operation while joining multiple data frame in spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to join two data frame and then apply a like operation on it. But it is not returning any value. I want to do a pattern match here. Any suggestion what i am doing wrong here.

```
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

val upcTable = spark.sqlContext.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
  Row(1, 50, 100),
  Row(2, 60, 200),
  Row(36, 70, 300),
  Row(45, 80, 400)
))

val lookupUpc = spark.sqlContext.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
 Row(3, 70, 300),
 Row(4, 80, 400)
))

val upcDf = spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame(upcTable, StructType(Seq(
  StructField("U_ID", StringType, nullable = false),
  StructField("V_ID", IntegerType, nullable = false),
  StructField("R_ID", IntegerType, nullable = false))))

val lookupDf = spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame(lookupUpc, StructType(Seq(
  StructField("U_ID", StringType, nullable = false),
  StructField("V_ID", IntegerType, nullable = false))))
lookupDf.show()

val joinDf = upcDf.join(lookupDf,Seq("V_ID"),"inner").filter(upcDf("U_ID").like("%lookupDf(U_ID)")).select(upcDf("U_ID"),upcDf("V_ID"),upcDf("R_ID")).show()
```

Here I wanted 36 and 45 from the upcDf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than column method [like](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column@like(literal:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) which expects a literal `String`, method [contains](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column@contains(other:Any):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) which takes an argument of type `Any` (hence also `Column`) would be more suitable in your case:

```
val joinDf = upcDf.join(lookupDf, Seq("V_ID"), "inner").
  where(upcDf("U_ID").contains(lookupDf("U_ID"))).
  select(upcDf("U_ID"), upcDf("V_ID"), upcDf("R_ID"))

joinDf.show
// +----+----+----+
// |U_ID|V_ID|R_ID|
// +----+----+----+
// |  45|  80| 400|
// |  36|  70| 300|
// +----+----+----+
```

Note that column `U_ID` in your sample dataset should be of `String` type based on the listed schemas.

[UPDATE]

As per clarified requirement from comments, if you want to limit the match to only the leading character I would suggest using method [regexp_extract](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@regexp_extract(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,exp:String,groupIdx:Int):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) and replace the above `where` clause with the following:

```
where(lookupDf("U_ID") === regexp_extract(upcDf("U_ID"), "^(.)", 1))
```

Comment: Thanks. But I am looking to match the first position only, not anywhere in the string..like the pattern matching

Comment: @Pradeep, please see my expanded answer.